# What is the correct way to calculate mean IoU in PyTorch when there are absent classes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, metrics

My use case is pretty much the same with this example:

```
from torchmetrics import JaccardIndex
import torch

pred = torch.tensor([1, 2, 19, 17, 17])
target = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 17, 4])

jaccard = JaccardIndex(num_classes=21)

jaccard(pred, pred)
Out: tensor([0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 0.])
```

How can I correctly calculate mIoU between pred and target when there are non-present classes? In other words, I don't want it to simply assign zero to classes that were not even present in the test dataset. Also, we need to consider the zeros only if it is really a wrong prediction, instead of an absent class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DeepLabV3Plus` metric class [here](https://github.com/VainF/DeepLabV3Plus-Pytorch/blob/master/metrics/stream_metrics.py).

```
metric = StreamSegMetrics(n_classes)
for batch_idx, _ in enumerate(dataLoader):
    metric.update(label_trues, label_preds) # update every iterations
    metrics_out = metric.get_results()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a brief aside on metrics, the purpose of which is to assess the goodness of an algorithmic approach at completing a task **with respect to a final use case of the approach.** Your final application of the algorithm should significantly inform how you craft your metrics. If you care deeply that the performance of your algorithm is class-balanced even at the expense of average performance, then you should balance your results per class. But if you instead want the best average performance for your application, you should probably use a metric that doesn't weight each class equally irrespective of relative class frequency. (It's also worth considering whether your dataset is representative of class distributions in the wild or class-biased). In a safety-critical application where some classes indicate danger, you may want to opt for metrics that encourage high recall over high precision. And if you don't understand how the torchmetrics implementation of the JaccardIndex weights each of these things it may be worth implementing it yourself to give a bit more flexibility (IOU for labels is basically trivial to implement). **Jaccard Index is also not incredibly useful for understanding multi-class performance as it doesn't distinguish between false positives and false negatives, and makes no determination of commonly confused classes.** It is most commonly used for multi-class problems on image segmentation tasks, which have a spatial element for which the notion of `overlap` is useful.

But in any case, here's how you'd implement for your desired question. Let `c` be the number of classes in your dataset. Jaccard Index is the interstection of two sets divided by the union of the two sets, so we'll find the interstection per-class (`bin_hits`) and the `union`) then divide (there are several feasible ways to do this divide operation yielding starkly different scores.)

```
bin_p = torch.bincount(pred,min_length = c)
bin_t = torch.bincount(target,min_length = c)

# mask is 1 if pred == target, 0 otherwise
hit_mask = 1 - torch.clamp((pred - target),min = 0, max = 1)

hits_class = pred[hit_mask.nonzero()]
bin_hits   = torch.bincount(hits_class,min_length = c)
union = bin_p + bin_t - bin_hits
```

At this point:

```
bin_p      = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0] 
bin_t      = [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0] 
hit_mask   = [1,1,0,1,0]
hits_class = [1,2,17]
bin_hits   = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
union      = [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0]
```

Per-class Jaccard Index (no reduction to a single value):

```
jaccard = bin_hits / union 

>>> result = [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0]
```

Basic Jaccard Index (no weighting by class). Note that classes with no predictions and no true labels do not affect the score as they affect neither sum:

```
jaccard = bin_hits.sum() / union.sum() 

>>> result = 3/7 = 0.42857
```

Mean Jaccard Index (each class counts for the same proportion of the total score). Note that classes with no predictions and no true labels do affect the score:

```
jaccard = (bin_hits / union).mean()

>>> result = 0.119
```

**Mean Jaccard Index with empty classes ignored**:

```
jaccard_per_class = (bin_hits / union)

# get class indices with at least one prediction or example
mask = (bin_p + bin_t).nonzero()         
jaccard = jaccard_per_class[mask] # takes mean of non-zero bins only

>>> result = 0.41667
```

Once again though, I'd encourage you to explore other metrics that are a bit more well-aligned with your task.